# sizeof in fortran

Tags: fortran, sizeof

It's quite common in C-code to see stuff like:

```
malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

which will return a pointer to a block of memory big enough to hold 100 ints.  Is there any equivalent in fortran?

---

Use case:

I have a binary file which is opened as:

```
open(unit=10,file='foo.dat',access='stream',form='unformatted',status='old')
```

I know that the file contains "records" which consist of a header with 20 integers, 20 real numbers and 80 characters, then another `N` real numbers.  Each file can have hundreds of records.  Basically, I'd like to read or write to a particular record in this file (assuming `N` is a fixed constant for simplicity).

I can easily calculate the position in the file I want to write if I know the size of each data-type:

```
header_size = SIZEOF_INT*20 + SIZEOF_FLOAT*20 + SIZEOF_CHAR*80
data_size = N*SIZEOF_FLOAT
position = (record_num-1)*(header_size+data_size)+1
```

Currently I have

```
!Hardcoded :-(
SIZEOF_INT = 4
SIZEOF_FLOAT = 4
SIZEOF_DOUBLE = 8
SIZEOF_CHAR = 1
```

Is there any way to do better?

**constraints:**

- The code is meant to be run on a variety of platforms with a variety of compilers.  A standard compliant solution is definitely preferred.

Comment: fortran 2008 has c_sizeof and there's also storage_size, but I suppose "variety of platforms and compilers" rules out the choice...

Comment: @ShinTakezou -- It's worth posting an answer though, for others who might not have a problem as constrained as mine (If it's in the 2008 standard, it's likely to become more and more supported by vendors as time passes ...)

Comment: The Fortran equivalent of your C code is to declare an array `integer, allocatable :: int_array(:)`, which is then allocated as `allocate(int_array(100))`. You could also allocate a `pointer` array, which would actually assign the pointer to a block of memory, but the allocatable is the preferred way.

Comment: @sigma -- Thanks for the comment.  I actually already know how to make allocatable arrays in fortran.  I was just showing one common use case for `sizeof` in C.  That was the first one that came to mind.

Comment: In the Fortran world, size in memory and size on disk are not necessarily the same, so the malloc example was perhaps unfortunate.  The C_SIZEOF path is limited to interoperable things.

Comment: @IanH -- then are you saying that the fortran standard does not provide means for a program to be restarted from exactly a point where it left off?

Comment: That's a different discussion (where you'd have to define "exactly" pretty exactly...).  Just saying that if you want to find out the size that something will occupy in memory (perhaps because you are going to call into C and get it to malloc some memory) - use C_SIZEOF (if the thing is interoperable).  If you want to know how many file storage units it will occupy - use INQUIRE.  Often the number will be the same between the two methods, but not on all platforms (and depending on what the specific things being sized are, the numbers can vary from platform to platform).

Comment: @mgilson: Oh, so that was an answer to the wrong question ;-). At least you should be able to remain standard-compliant and avoid hardcoding anything, using the intrinsic modules. They are already widely supported by compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your use case I think you could use

```
inquire(iolength=...) io-list
```

That will give you how many "file storage units" are required for the io-list. A caveat with calculating offsets in files with Fortran is that "file storage unit" need not be in bytes, and indeed I recall one quite popular compiler by default using a word (4 bytes) as the file storage unit. However, by using the iolength thing you don't need to worry about this issue.

Comment: Are you implying that `read(unit,pos=n) data` does not necessarily read data starting at the `n`'th byte in the file (opened as `form='unformatted',access='stream'`)? ... If that's the case, that's the sort of thing that really makes me frustrated with fortran ...

Comment: Digging deeper -- paraphrased from the 2008 standard -- "The number of bits in a "file storage unit" is given by the constant `FILE_STORAGE_SIZE` defined in the intrinsic module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`.  It is recommended that the file storage size be an 8-bit octet (1-byte) where this choice is practical."

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, the standard unfortunately leaves things like these up to the compiler. The module you found is provided to alleviate some of the resulting issues. It also defines named constants for the supported variable kinds, and the `iso_c_binding` module further provides these for C data types like `c_int` and `c_double`.

Comment: Thought I'd also add here for clarity that `read(unit, pos=n) data` technically reads from the n-th file storage unit. For each element in `data`, a number of `storage_size(data)/file_storage_size` positions are read from an unformatted stream file.

Answer (score 5):

@janneb's answer will address the OP's question, but it doesn't answer the "sizeof" question for Fortran.

A combination of `inquire` and `file_storage_size` will give the size of a type.  Try this code:

```
program sizeof
    use iso_fortran_env
    integer :: num_file_storage_units
    integer :: num_bytes
    inquire(iolength=num_file_storage_units) 1.0D0
    num_bytes = num_file_storage_units*FILE_STORAGE_SIZE/8
    write(*,*) "double has size: ", num_bytes
end program sizeof
```

See:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fFORTRAN_005fENV.html
http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0514.htm

Answer (score 1):

If all the records are the same, this would seem to be a case to use direct access rather than stream access.  Then don't calculate the position in the file, you tell the compiler the record that you want, and it accesses it.    Unless you want these files to be portable across platforms or the records are not all the same ... then you have to have more control or calculate the length of the records.  While the original Fortran 90 concept was to declare variables according to the required precision, there are now portable ways to declare variables by size.  Either with types provided by the already mentioned iso_c_binding module, or from the iso_fortran_env module.

Comment: For my use, the records are all the same, but with the file type, I don't really think that they should *have* to be.  Since the header actually contains the information to calculate how many elements of what type are stored, with that information, you can quickly iterate through the file and pull out the record that you want.  In fact, I originally got the idea from a program which wrote record-based direct access unformatted files ... Also, stream access just seems more natural since most of the processing will be done in python, which accesses the file in a more stream-like manner